# Swagger avoid removing common prefix

Tags: enums, swagger, swagger-codegen

How to skip removing the common prefix from modelsEnum name?
I have got an enum with single value (in the future I will have more values) and swagger code gen plugin generates the class with enum **CODE** instead of **AIRPORT_CODE**

```
properties:
  type:
    enum: ["AIRPORT_CODE"]
    description: the type of location that is identified by the value
```

Comment: Your problem is right here https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/0ce6c7e3a8ad93c8c8a49b41b75a7f31561d75ce/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/DefaultCodegen.java#L3443 and it doesn't seem to be a way to change this behavior without modifying that method (or overriding it in the class corresponding to the language you want). You might want to choose a format for your enums that isn't catch by the `findCommonPrefixOfVars` method (if you can).

Answer (score 2):

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/4331) that adds the `--use-enum-common-prefix` argument to address this issue, but it's not merged into master yet (as of time of writing). You can follow issue [#4261](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4261) for updates.

For now you can try rebuilding swagger-codegen yourself with this PR included, and use your custom build to generate the code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to overwrite the default configuration with: removeEnumValuePrefix=false

Examples:

Maven:

```
<configuration>
...
   <additionalProperties>
      <additionalProperty>removeEnumValuePrefix=false</additionalProperty>
   </additionalProperties>
</configuration>
```

Gradle:

```
openApiGenerate {
   ...
   additionalProperties = [
      removeEnumValuePrefix: "false"
   ]
}
```

For more details you can also take a look here: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/5166

Comment: sadly works only in v2, not in version 3 :(